# Category and Subcategory formula in Sharepoint list and no coding

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, formula

I am trying to create a calculated formula in Sharepoint List.
I like to create 2 columns(continent and country) with default country.
E.g. Continents are North America and South America.  When you select North America, only Canada and US are the choices and when selecting South America only Mexico and Brazil are showing for selection.  Also for each Continent, I like to defaulted a country, E.g. North America by default Canada selected

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about seems to be the cascading drop-down list. If you do not want to handle any code or scripts, it will not be a quite perfect one. Some workarounds are listed [here](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-alternatives-to-building-cascading-drop-downs-in-sharepoint/).
If having access, using [InfoPath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH7xUEcQwwg) or [PowerApps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzvMbmb5pmo) is also an option for you: